# Before reading a file, do I have to check ANSI encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, file, encoding

Im reding some csv files. The files are really easy, because there is always just "**;**" as seperator and there are no **"**, **'**, or something like that.

So its possible to read the file, line by line and seperate the strings. Thats working fine. Now people told me: maybe you should check the encoding of the file, it should be always ANSI, if its not maybe your output will be different and corrupted. So non-ansi files should be marked somehow.

I just said, okey! But if I think about it: do I really have to check the file for encoding in this case? I just changed the encoding of the file to something else and Im still able to read the file without any problems. My code is simple:

```
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(myFileStream))
{
  while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    //read the line, spererate by ; and other stuff...
  }
}
```

So again: do I really need to check the files for ANSI encoding? Could somebody give me an example when could I get in trouble or when do I get a corrupted output after reading a non-ansi file? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

That particular constructor of `StreamReader` will assume that the data is UTF-8; that is compatible with ASCII, but can fail if data uses bytes in the 128-255 range for single-byte codepages (you'll get the wrong characters in strings, etc), or could fail *completely* (i.e. throw an exception) if the data is actually something very different like UTF-7, UTF-32, etc.

In some cases (the minority) you might be able to use the byte-order-mark to detect the encoding, but this is a circular problem: in most cases, if you don't already *know* the encoding, you can't really *detect* the encoding (robustly). So a better approach would be: to know the encoding in the first place. Then you can pass in the ***correct*** encoding to use via one of the other constructors.

Here's an example of it failing:

```
// we'll write UTF-32, big-endian, without a byte-order-mark
File.WriteAllText("my.txt", "Hello world", new UTF32Encoding(true, false));

using (var reader = new StreamReader("my.txt"))
{
    string s = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run under `UTF-8` encoding , cause `UTF-8` has a wonderful  property support *ASCII* characters with `1` byte (as it would expected), but when it needed, shrink to support *Unicode* ones.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)